# html app-like pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a tutorial or websites that describes how tools like deck.js or html5rocks work. What I want to learn is to make app-like webpages with the ability to switch to a new page without reloading and with some nice animations.

I'm really sorry to bother you with this, but all my searches lead to manuals for creating presentations with that frameworks.

Comment: You could also skim through the source for those applications to look what techniques they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is information on Single-Page Applications, or SPA for those in the know.  I have not had much experience with Deck.js, but from what I just saw it looks pretty impressive.  In my opinion, the foundation for a great SPA app is Knockout.js and jQuery.  It doesn't appear that Deck deals with any model binding, change tracking, etc, so you should be fine to mix that in with a SPA app pretty easily.  There are a lot of really great tutorials out there, John Papa just posted an excellent presentation on PluralSight.com about SPA development and architecture.

After spending close to a year working with various forms of SPAs, I can tell you that an application that never "reloads" can run into some pretty wild issues; memory management being the big one.  I have opted towards sectional reloads, as in each site "section" will be single-page, but you load each section with a postback.  This allows you to clear out any memory issues, bindings, etc, and will make the application run much smoother in the long run.  That is, until all the issues with memory are a thing of the past...

Hope all this helped, best of luck!

Comment: not true, my "web app" is very sizable and is very fast, you just have to know how to clear unused data correctly.

Comment: Every conference I have attended, I asked any SPA presenters about memory management, and they all say it is an issue over time.  If you have spent the time researching the best methods, and understand how to manipulate the DOM, handle event handlers, prevent collection in detached dom, etc, it is not as much of a problem.  But, apparent through his question, this may not be the level of developer we are dealing with.  I do agree with you though.

Comment: yes absolutely agree, so for all intesive purposes, if you don't know how to clear memory to prevent a browser crash, stay away from web apps. haha

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to learn this the hard way on my first SPA.  No namespacing, not objects, just nasty jQuery on doc.ready, lol.  Was not a fun one to refactor.

Comment: yuck! i'm not a big jquery fan either, so bloated but you can't beat their easy calls and extensive library.  you have any demos of your work?

Comment: That is what made it so attractive, didn't have to learn a a lot, just needed to code.  Not currently, been planning on getting a blog up to post stuff like that, just not enough time lately.

Comment: takes alot of time(ALOT) to get something good anyway

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The term Singel-Page Application is what I am looking for. I was searching for things like "multi page" and found stuff about iframes or very basic stuff like linking pages. Further I am more looking for the visual representation than the logic happening with tools like MVC-frameworks.

Comment: @jaheba, just so you know how things work, if someone answers your question you should select the checkmark beside their post (indicating this was the resolution for you).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that go to jquerymobile.com. Use their framework as if you were going to make an app and scale it to webpage. but the "technology" you should look into is ajax, which refreshes data without a page refresh etc etc. also jquery (for websites) can help you with slides pops etc. FOREWARNING, barely if at all works for IE

http://jquerymobile.com/

Use this to start you off, they have a pretty cool drag n drop feature which you can see their code and it will connect events for you, it will get you started

Comment: "i dont know if you have been on this site long" - 1 rep, joined today.

Comment: didn't look, but theres your answer anyway, use jquery's library for ajax and their SUPER easy functions for slides fades etc. also upvote or accept thanks.

Comment: First, if you had taken the time to see that it is a new member, joining today, perhaps you could cut a little him/her a bit of slack.  As he/she may not be up to speed on how we do things around here.  Secondly, I have built numerous SPA/AJAX/JS sites that work perfectly in all modern browsers.  I don't know what your issue has been with IE, but my experience is it works the same with exception to the visual arena, which can require a bit of research and CSS modifications...

Comment: thats exactly the problem. Animations suck. And if you look at task manager while using a site with "effects" see how IE uses a ton more system resources because it doesnt have good graphics rendering. also, its a pain in the ass in general. But yes, not impossible.

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey i wasn't "scolding" them either just a forewarning because of my first day here i pretty much got crucified for a question, and wanted to give the heads up, didn't want to sound condescending.

Comment: Well then, I retract my "First" comment :)

Comment: Thank you too for your answer. I know that developers don't like these kinds of questions, but since I stuck I wanted to try this site. All I needed was a buzzword (Single Page Application) to search further for my self. Instead of using a framework like jquerymobile I want to do it by myself to learn the techniques.

Comment: im not telling you to use jquery mobile. just as a guideline to start you off. use REGULAR jquery as they have a cool library to buffer elements so they can slide. unless your SPECTACULAR at coding you will never get transitions and animations to work on IE.